# problem related to tensorflow module -ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn'

Tags: python, tensorflow

[image]

This image describes my problem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn'

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to the latest version of TFLearn.

`pip install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git`

Comment: @Ashifkasala You're welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer as well.